# JQuery intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: jquery, ide, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I decided to jump in Visual Studio Code to create an app.
Now I can't seem to get intellisense working for both JQuery and JQuery Mobile.

My VSC version is 0.10.1

I tried adding a `reference.d.ts` file with this contents

```
/// <reference path="js/jquery.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="js/jquerymobile.d.ts"/>
```

(files downloaded from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)

I tried opening a `.js` file, add a `$(this)` and hitting ctrl+period but it
says 'No suggestions'.

Something I missed?

**UPDATE:**

Tried adding a `jsconfig.json` file following https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson

```
{
    "files": [
        "js/jquery.d.ts",
        "js/jquerymobile.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Restarted, nothing...

**UPDATE 2:**

added a `.js` file, typed `$` and clicked on the lightbulb to download jquery.d.ts file. It warns me about adding this file to the jsconfig.json file.
After doing all this, restarted still not working.

`jsconfig.json` file contents:

```
{
    "files": [
        "typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Nothing!

Comment: I just tried renamin reference.d.ts to _references.js, restarted VSC but still nothing..

Comment: Same problem here. No matter what setup I try, VS Code won't autocomplete jQuery. Microsoft's documentation isn't all that helpful either.

Answer (score 25):

Latest (as of April 2017) suggested approach to do this is to use automatic type acquisition by adding `jsconfig.json` file in the root of your project with the following contents:

```
{
 "typeAcquisition": {
     "include": [
         "jquery"
     ]
   }
}
```

Then, in your editor you will see:

[image: jquery intellisense in Visual Studio Code]

For more information, check [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense)

Comment: can I also do this with angularjs?

Comment: This worked for me on one machine but not another (same repo). Any clue what the hangup might be?

Answer (score 7):

If you are already familiar with npm (if not you should)

I suggest you install [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) which is a typeScript definition manager that work very well with Visual Studio Code (Tested on Mac and Windows)

Simply run

```
npm install typings --global
```

Of course you must need to have npm already [installed](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm) on your local pc/mac.

After that, move to the command line (terminal or cmd) and run

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

It will create the typings directory and all required files (not need to restart Visual Studio Code) and you are ready to go!.

If you want to know more about typings just follow the typings link above.

Comment: tsd install jquery prints zero results , any tips ?

Comment: `tsd` is deprecated, you can run `npm install typings --global`

Comment: typings install dt~jquery --global --save
/
(node:11656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (reje
ction id: 2): PopsicleError: Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entri
es/dt/jquery/versions/latest"
\

Answer (score 4):

step 1 : 
make sure you have the definition files in your project
if you got npm installed then run

```
npm i --save-dev @types/jquery
```

it will install jQuery definition file in node_modules/@types/jquery
else :
download it. and put it in any folder 
then ,
step:2 
create a jsconfig.json file

```
$ touch jsconfig.json
```

and put this code in the jsconfig.json file

```
{
    "include": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules"
    ]
}
```

that's it .

**

> note : i am excluding ./node_modules in case you have it in your
>   project if not then just include the jquery.d.ts file .

**

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a little bit problem with it, so I would like to share the solution that worked for me.
At first you need in project root package.json if you don't have it in console simply type:

```
$ npm init
```

this command should create a package.json with necessary content in it.
Then run this command in console:

```
$ npm install --save @types/jquery
```

and like @oldbam said before use automatic type acquisition:
by creating jsonconfig.json with code below:

```
    {
 "typeAcquisition": {
     "include": [
         "jquery"
     ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

under `typings/` directory create a file called "tsd.d.ts"  with the following content:

```
/// <reference path="js/jquery.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="js/jquerymobile.d.ts"/>
```

jsconfig.json need not contain the files attribute:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and restarted but still not working. If I edit a standalone .js file and type $(this) I get the lightbulb that suggests to download the jquery.d.ts file and it does so. It also suggests the following:
typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts successfully downloaded. Make sure the d.ts file is included your project's 'jsconfig.json'.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using typings 1.x, you should use:

typings install dt~jquery --global

in typing 1.x, there's much changes .

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't forget to add the reference to the d.ts file in your scripts. For eg. add this reference `/// <reference path="js/jquery.d.ts"/>` at the top of the script you want to see the jquery suggestions as you type.