# jQuery intellisense in VS Code

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have tried this:

[JQuery intellisense in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902077/jquery-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code)

and this:

http://shrekshao.github.io/2016/06/20/vscode-01/

But it does nothing, VS Code just won't add jquery intellisense, I've been trying to solve this for hours but it just won't work

Comment: Can you give some more information.

Comment: I've tried everything shown on the links, what else do you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery intellisense in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902077/jquery-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 102):

Most of the blog postings are now outdated, as we finally have automatic type acquisition with version 1.8+ - you no longer need to install the typings yourself.

I recommend reading the official documentation, its always up to date: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

If you use npm and have a `package.json` in your project and jQuery is listed there, it should already work.

If you do not use npm, you can create the file `jsconfig.json` in the project root with the following content and you are good to go:

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jquery"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: hi kwood, can i add jquery intellisense to vs code without a project? i edit many arbitrary js files in different environments.

Comment: This worked for me on one machine but not on another. (Same repo on both.) Any insight into what might prevent jquery support when it's manually included like this?

Comment: @anaval : Just tested, it works for `AngularJS` too:

`"typeAcquisition": {  "include": [  "jquery",  "angular"  ]  }`

Comment: I had to delete the jsconfig.json file and use the approach below with npm. I also had to restart vs code in order to get it to recognize that I had installed node. I have to say, this a ridiculous pain in the ass for both VS Code and full VS 2022. Not happy right now.

Answer (score 19):

Type this command in your project root :

```
npm i --save @types/jquery
```

Comment: i tried installing it globally. It got added to the global modules
but did not take effect in vs code. 
Any ideas ? (and yes i have tried closing and opening vs code after i installed it globally)

Comment: @eranotzap I believe this command has to be run in a project and not globally. When you install it globally it does not work.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and google brought me here.  I added the type jsconfig.json and "typeAcquisition" and still nothing.

Turns out you have to have node and npm installed. Even if you are not using them for package management and are importing jquery from a CDN.

From the Docs

> Many popular libraries ship with typings files so you get IntelliSense for them automatically. For libraries that do not include typings, VS Code's Automatic Type Acquisition will automatically install community maintained typings file for
>
> Automatic type acquisition requires npmjs, the Node.js package manager, which is included with the Node.js runtime. In this image you can see IntelliSense, including the method signature, parameter info, and the method's documentation for the popular lodash library.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

So vs code uses npm for auto type acquisition.

May be super basic, but it solved my problem so I hope it helps someone else too.

*I also used the configuration in jsconfig.json as described by kwood. Not sure I needed to specify it manually after installin npm but it is working so i'm not asking questions*

Answer (score 4):

What helped me was using the non-minified version of jQuery, and then use

```js
/// <reference path="./jquery-3.4.1.js" />
```

in the beginning of my JS file.

(I'm coding client-side i.e. ES5 JavaScript that is added to the page directly with the `<script>` tag.)

Answer (score 3):

I thought that the major reason is Vscode does not parse the Jquery.js file because original jquery file is minified, which leads to vscode stop tokenization of the file.
To solve this, open the jquery.js file, right click and select format. The tokenization process will complete.