# Automatic Type Acquisition in VSCode on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm at my wits end with this.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902077/jquery-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code#34837985), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975036/how-to-import-intellisense-files-into-vscode-visual-studio-code) and [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) amongst others. I've spent two days on it and gotten nowhere. During the process I upgraded to VSCode 1.16.0 so I'm fully up-to-date.

In my final attempt, I tried to go as simple as possible. So I did the following:

1. Create test project directory `vscodetest`
2. `cd` into `vscodetest`
3. open vscode using vscode . from terminal
4. add new JavaScript file `app.js`
5. add `jsconfig.json` with the following configuration

```html
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jquery"
        ]
    }
}
```

6. In `app.js` start typing the following...

```html
var f = $('sdsf').
```

When I hit <kbd>.</kbd>, *(period)* Intellisense just gives me `$` and `f`.

Help appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want Intellisense code completion for whichever npm JavaScript package I'm referencing. In this case, jQuery.

Comment: Can you please file an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new I can help you collect logs and investigate what may be going wrong but SO is not really the best format for this

Comment: Hi, Matt. Thanks. I will do. I didn't go directly to logging an issue because I thought I might be doing something stupid (usually the case). I'll get on it now.

Comment: OK. That's done now.